# Where are iOS simulator files?

Tags: xcode, macos-sierra

So because of the poor internet connect I have in China, I downloaded iOS 9.3 simulator SDK from here via multithreads web connection: `devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK9_3-9.3.1.1460411551.dmg`

After installation the simulator doesn't show up in my hardware (Xcode menu), so I guess it wasn't compatible with the newest Xcode 8.3.2, yet it does take up additional 3.6 GB storage space of my laptop (of which only has 9 GB left right now). I then left the laptop on and downloaded the SDK from Xcode directly and installed it successfully, the problem is that it didn't remove the 3.6 GB files from previous installation so now I have less than 1 GB left on my laptop. I like to find out where the SDK is and manually remove them to free up storage space on my laptop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes`

Answer (score 10):

In 2021 onwards, the device emulator files be found at `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/`, but this contains all simulators installed, which is currently 24 devices on my machine.

`~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$DEVICE_ID/data/Library`

**To find out your simulator device id:**

0. Launch your simulator
1. `xcrun simctl list 'devices' 'booted'`

```
== Devices ==
-- iOS 14.4 --
    iPhone 12 Pro (1320D7BA-FB2E-4E1C-834B-09BE5031054B) (Booted)
    iPhone 12 Pro Max (91512DCC-DCEA-4ED4-9731-52D895399940) (Booted)
-- tvOS 14.3 --
-- watchOS 7.2 --
```

2. `cd /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/91512DCC-DCEA-4ED4-9731-52D895399940/data` would contain these files:

[image]

### Extra: how to get a Application.app to run on simulator

For example, you could take this app and share it with someone else.

```
cd /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/emulator_id/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/
ls # This will list all the application directories, where each directory contains a `.app` file which will work on emulators.
```

You can drag this `.app` file onto another simulator and it will install.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Disk Inventory X Application to spot large files in your mac. It is very useful to remove and free up some space.
Anyway, answering your question, the simulator files is in `/Users/[Your user account name]/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS`
you should be able to find those unused file there

Comment: Disk Inventory X didn't find the files. It's also not in `/Users/[Your user account name]/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with this problem, is using an app called `DaisyDisk`, because XCode download new simulators every time iOS update, today you have iOS 10.3.x, even you delete those, XCode will download iOS 10.4.x or iOS 11 again in the future, you'd have to manually delete those files again.

Using `DaisyDisk` makes discovering these simulators, as well as deleting them fairly easy, I strongly recommend you to try it.

Bravo Apple for making 128G Mac users suffer :)